# how to recover deleted records from table in sql

Tags: sql

By mistake I Delete rows from table. I tried following opetions
  1) use query

```
use DB_FRS 
go
SELECT 
[Current LSN],    
[Transaction ID],
 Operation,
 Context,
 AllocUnitName

FROM 
  fn_dblog(NULL, NULL) 
WHERE 
Operation = 'LOP_DELETE_ROWS'
```

In this option, I did not get any rows

2) Use APEXSQL
But I don't have any credential to do changes

Is ther any other option . Please help me.

Comment: Backup the most reliable solution

Comment: Check this: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/995/how-do-i-get-back-some-deleted-records

Comment: Check [LINK](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3160/recover-deleted-sql-server-data-and-tables-with-the-help-of-transaction-log-and-lsns/)

Answer (score 0):

The way I have had to do this in the past is to restore the most recent backup to a temporary database and query for the deleted records and insert them back into the database.

Comment: I dont have any backup

Comment: Hmmm, I am not sure what else to suggest.  I am not familiar with object-level recovery tools like APEX.  But I do strongly suggest that if you care about the data that you ensure you have regular backups (and test them) the frequency of which will depend on how much data you would be happy to lose.  Sorry, hope you get your data back.